# what is used to write functions within mongoDB/mongolite?

Tags: r, mongodb

I'm learning mongolite/mongoDB right now, and came across this:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/vignettes/intro.html

Inside I saw code like this:

```
tbl <- m$mapreduce(
  map = "function(){emit({cut:this.cut, color:this.color}, 1)}",
  reduce = "function(id, counts){return Array.sum(counts)}"
)
```

Can someone tell me what these functions are written in? I don't think they are R functions.

Comment: those are monodb-flavored javascript functions. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#return-the-total-price-per-customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R language allows you to create environments where you put functions that are then referenced with the $-operator as one would pull items from a list. So the `m$mapreduce` is calling an R function and sending that text to the database engine: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/ 
If you install the package and execute `help(pac=mongolite)` you will see that the package has a single exposed function, `mongo` that allows any of those function calls. You can then work through the examples on the help page and the vignette.

(Note: you will get an error if you do not first install and set up the database executable.)

If you execute this with mongolite loaded you get a list of objects in the environment defined when the mongo function was created:

```
ls(envir=environment(mongo))
```

There are a set of objects in that environment that appear to hold what you might be interested in:

```
[14] "mongo_collection_aggregate"       
[15] "mongo_collection_command"         
[16] "mongo_collection_command_simple"  
[17] "mongo_collection_count"           
[18] "mongo_collection_create_index"    
[19] "mongo_collection_distinct"        
[20] "mongo_collection_drop"            
[21] "mongo_collection_drop_index"      
[22] "mongo_collection_find"            
[23] "mongo_collection_find_indexes"    
[24] "mongo_collection_insert_bson"     
[25] "mongo_collection_insert_page"     
[26] "mongo_collection_mapreduce"       
[27] "mongo_collection_name"            
[28] "mongo_collection_new"             
[29] "mongo_collection_remove"          
[30] "mongo_collection_rename"          
[31] "mongo_collection_stats"           
[32] "mongo_collection_update"
```

Comment: hmm I don't seem to see these functions in the environment, such as ```emit``` and ```Array.sum```

Comment: Those would appear to be intended for interpretation by the database Javascript engine. See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/

Answer (score 1):

The mapreduce functions in the mongolite package are written in javascript. Please see the package docs on CRAN for confirmation (page 3) [(a link to external PDF)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/mongolite.pdf):

```
mapreduce(map, reduce, query = ’{}’, sort = ’{}’, limit = 0, out = NULL, scope = NULL)
```

"*Performs a map reduce query. The map and reduce arguments are strings containing a JavaScript function. Set out to a string to store results in a collection instead of returning.*"